# How EventEmitter wakeup listeners are counted?

Tags: node.js, event-handling

Questions about the warning `Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` have been asked a lot.

But what I dont get is **How the wakeup listeners are counted ?**

The Node documentation says:

> The eventEmitter.on() method is used to register listeners, while the eventEmitter.emit() method is used to trigger the event.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

So then, this piece of code totalise 6 eventEmitter.on(), so how come it can generate the warning ?

```
var express         = require('express');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var request         = require('request');
var http            = require('http');
var moment          = require('moment');
const apn           = require("apn");
const EventEmitter  = require('eventemitter3');
var jsonfile        = require('jsonfile');
var emoji           = require('node-emoji');



var ee = new EventEmitter();

ee.on("MorseOK", function () {
});

ee.on("DateOK", function () {
});

ee.on("MsgFailed", function () {
});

ee.on("TEST_NOTIFS", function () {
});

ee.on("LOAD_TOKENS", function () {
});

ee.on("SAVE_TOKENS", function () {
});

function sendNotificationToIPhone(text) {
    /* ... */
}

function timerCallback() {
    /* ... */
};

setInterval(timerCallback, global.the_interval);

timerCallback()


var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/api/messages', function (req, res) {  
    /* ... */
});

app.post('/api/client', function (req, res) {  
    /* ... */
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    /* ... */
});

app.get('/api/test/sendnotifs', function (req, res) {
    /* ... */
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    /* ... */
});


ee.emit("LOAD_TOKENS");
```

Also, the warning says `wakeup listeners` but the documentation doesn't contain the word `wakeup`, so I am not sure to understand what the warning is referring.